# Review queue suddenly filled up

Tags: bug

Suddenly, about 200 late answers showed up in the review queue, some more than a year old. Is this a bug or a feature?

[image: 171 Late Answers]

Comment: yes. i have just see that . in my account it show 184. I am worried about it..https://twitter.com/dev_amitbera/status/648956578733756416

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just got answer from Marius.This is a **feature** and not a **bug**.

***He  referred this meta question*** [Why did the late answer queue spike on Sep 29, 2015?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267081/why-did-the-late-answer-queue-spike-on-sep-29-2015) to see why it increased

It was expected to work a bit differently, though:

> [image: comments]

***More details can see at*** [Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to enter the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue)

Comment: Looks like there was a bug in the feature, though. Answers older than a month should not have shown up. I added a screenshot of the relevant comment thread to the answer.

Comment: @fschmengler..thanks for update the answer....